# Ionic-item- Customize padding between icon and text?

Tags: sass, ionic2

I'm designing a side menu. I would like to reduce the padding between `ion-icon` and `title` that is placed inside `ion-item`. I tried to override the `ion-item` sass properties but it doesn't help out.

```
<button menuClose ion-item *ngIf="!option.subItems" class="menu-style"
              (click)="openPage(option)">
          <ion-icon [name]="option.iconName" item-left color="primary"></ion-icon>
          {{ option.displayName }}
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the `sass` attributes of the component using the features in web browsers in that way you can figure out it effortlessly. You can override the `ion-item` style in the following way.

```
.item ion-icon[item-left]+.item-inner,
.item ion-icon[item-left]+.item-input {
    margin-left: 10px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this today.  The issue is that you can't really change the styling unless the icon is inside a `div`.  However, that means you have to display the `div` with `display:inline` and that makes things like `margin` and `width` unavailable.  Further, `padding` didn't seem to do anything.

I was able to solve this with an additional wrapper/parent `div` with `relative` positioning, making the inner icon parent `div` display with `absolute` positioning, which is great because you can absolutely position the icon but relative to the inline parent:

```
Search 
<div style="position:relative;display:inline">
  <!-- transparent placeholder for width -->
  <ion-icon name="search" style="color:transparent"></ion-icon>

  <!-- positioned/displayed icon -->
  <div style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:3px">
    <ion-icon name="search" color="primary"></ion-icon>
  </div>
</div>
```

That code makes the `div` right after the `Search` text appear directly to the right or inline with the other text.  Then, you can see `div style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:3px"` is used to absolutely position the icon.

The reason I added the transparent icon is because, again, using `display:inline` means you cannot specify a width and so providing the transparent version of the same thing guarantees the same width.  Basically, you are hiding the badly positioned icon - only using it for a width placeholder - and displaying the correctly positioned icon.